# Can iOS 8 native credit card scanning be utilized in a native app?

Tags: ios, ios8, mobile-safari, credit-card

In iOS 8, a user can scan his or her credit card (takes a picture) in both Safari and Apple Pay. Additionally, a web form can prompt a user to scan a credit card to autofill a form asking for payment info. This is done in html by setting a tag / name on the field, e.g. "..." Safari will then automaticaly prompt the user to use their camera (see links below).

Is there a way to take advantage of this functionality in a native iOS app, either via an apple API or by setting some field type parameters on an input field?
Example use case: user opens my app and tries to buy something, I prompt user to enter a credit card, she or he can then scan a card.

If a user adds a card directly through Safari settings they might have this option:
https://9to5mac.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/2014-10-02-08-41-21.png

If a user hasn't added a card already, they might have this option:
http://photos2.appleinsidercdn.com/gallery/9512-1291-safari-140609-l.png

NOTE: I know about Card.io and will probably use that, but wanted to find out if there is an easier / more seamless way.

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, I never saw it outside of a webview.
Card.io is the best option in my opinion.

Comment: Please suggest anything other than Card.io and free of cost.